# ES2015 template strings security issue

Tags: javascript, security, ecmascript-6

Here's a quote from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings):

> Template strings MUST NOT be constructed by untrusted users, because they have access to variables and functions.

And an example:

```
`${console.warn("this is",this)}`; // "this is" Window

let a = 10;
console.warn(`${a+=20}`); // "30"
console.warn(a); // 30
```

The example here doesn't show any vulnerabilities I can see.

Can anyone give an example of an exploit that takes advantage of this?

Comment: that has nothing to do with template strings

Comment: That's eval(). It's already dangerous. Also, that's not a template string.

Comment: Maybe see who added the comment on MDN and ask them why?

Comment: You can ask the author of [the revision](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings$compare?to=775147&from=766983) via [his twitter](https://twitter.com/KOLANICH) for details.

Comment: Looks like that quote has been removed today. Also looks like the [GitHub history](https://github.com/mdn/content/commits/01ff31c3d7c6818de4b0cdd3c130ab7ccc948856/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/template_literals/index.html?browsing_rename_history=true&new_path=files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/template_literals/index.md&original_branch=main) of the current doc only goes back as far as 2020.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This makes no sense. A template string doesn't have access to anything, it is not executed either. A template string is a syntactical element of the language.

Dynamically constructing a template string is no problem therefore - it's like building an expression (in whatever format, be it a code string or an AST). The problem MDN hints at is with evaluating such an expression (e.g. using `eval`, serialising it into a script that is served to the user, etc.) - it may contain arbitrary code, in contrast to a string literal! But of course you wouldn't do that anyway, would you?

This warning is like saying "*Concatenations using the `+` operator must not be constructed by untrusted users, because they have access to variables and functions.*" and giving the example `"" + console.warn("this is",this) + ""` for it. Well, this is true for any expression of the language, so it's not particularly interesting.

---

While we are talking about crappy coding, there is of course a scenario where using template strings (hey, they're multiline and whatnot) instead of string literals can lead to problems:

```
function escapeString(str) {
    return JSON.stringify(str).slice(1, -1)
           .replace(/\u2028/g, "\\u2028").replace(/\u2029/g, "\\u2029");
}

// This is (kinda) fine!
var statement = 'var x = "Hello,\\n'+escapeString(userInput)+'";';
eval(statement); // some kind of evaluation

// But this is not:
var statement = 'var x = `Hello,\n'+escapeString(userInput)+'`;';
//                       ^                                   ^
```

Now imagine `userInput` contains a `${…}` - which we did not escape…

Comment: Naturally. The example on MDN, however, shows what you invalidate in the first paragraph.

Comment: @Mosho: I don't see any construction of a template string in that example anyway

Comment: What do you mean? talking about this: ``${console.warn("this is",this)}``

Comment: That's a template string where a part of it is substituted with the result of the expression `console.warn("this is", this)`, yes. But how did that expression get there in the first place? Not by dynamic construction or anything.

Comment: Gotcha and yeah, exactly. The example is totally useless.

Comment: It's like saying "*Concatenations using the `+` operator must not be constructed by untrusted users, because they have access to variables and functions.*" with the example `"" + console.warn("this is",this) + ""`

Comment: Yeah, you nailed it. I would add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think @Bergi is correct - the danger here involves using `eval` or similar methods to allow a user to construct the actual *template string*, not the substitutions.

**Example exploit**: A lazy developer wants to allow users to perform some string substitutions in their comments, e.g. to reference other users or questions, on a site like SO. Instead of developing tokens for this and then doing appropriate parsing and substitution, he decides he'll accept syntax like this:

```
"I think ${firstPoster} is an idiot! See ${question(1234)} for details!"
```

and run it through a function like this:

```
var firstPoster = {...};
function question() {...}

processInput(input) {
  return eval('`' + input + '`');
}
```

If this code is `eval`'d on the client and shown to other users, a malicious user could inject an [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attack. If it's `eval`'d on the server, the attacker could take control of the machine.

Comment: the problem though at this point is that the template string is the least of the worries.

Comment: This is kind of a stretch, and I doubt it was the author's intent given the example.

Comment: This is simply mis-using `eval()` with template strings being incidental.

Comment: @KarelG - well, I called them "lazy", but maybe I'm nicer :)

Answer (score 1):

The example no longer seems to be in the MDN docs. As [Bergi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936136/5134722) points out, the given example doesn't seem to highlight anything special about template strings.

However, when it comes to building strings from objects, there is a particular security concern you should definitely be aware of:

**The `toString()` method will be called implicitly on a non-string object if it is passed to a string interpolation / concatenation expression.**

There are probably also other cases where `toString()` is called implicitly. But string interpolation seems to me to be one of the most common ones; indeed, it's one I experience regularly. For example, suppose you somehow receive an object from somewhere external e.g. via an `iframe` through `postMessage`. In that case, you might want to do something like log the message received to the console - and you might be tempted to just pass the object right into an interpolated string.

But the sender (possibly an attacker) has full control over the definition of `toString()` and can insert whatever code they like in there. So as soon as you pass that object to the interpolated *or* concatenated string, you are vulnerable as long as someone else controls the definition of said object.

Here is a simple example (added to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vanilla-js-local-storage-forked-fitgp6?file=/src/index.js:0-731)), showing that even if objects return seemingly harmless strings in `toString()`, they can indeed do dangerous stuff like read you local storage:

```
import "./styles.css";

localStorage.setItem("secret1", "sssh! One");
localStorage.setItem("secret2", "sssh! Two");

const evilObject1 = {
  toString() {
    alert("I stole a secret: " + localStorage.getItem("secret1"))
    return "I'm innocent";
  }
};

const evilObject2 = {
  toString() {
    alert("I stole a secret: " + localStorage.getItem("secret2"))
    return "I'm innocent";
  }
};

const strInter = `Seemingly innocent object, interpolated: ${evilObject1}`;
const strConcat = "Seemingly innocent object, concatenated: " + evilObject2;

let p = document.createElement("p");
p.innerHTML = strInter
let p2 = document.createElement("p");
p2.innerHTML = strConcat
document.body.appendChild(p);
document.body.appendChild(p2);
```

With Javascript, being duck-typed, this is quite a real vulnerability, because you might *think* that the object you receive (e.g. via `postMessage`) is a string, and indeed, it may behave like a string (because it has a cleverly designed `toString()` method), but unless you dynamically check the types you don't know if you actually got a string.

If you're expecting a string, you can fix the above vulnerability as follows:

```
const sanitized1 = typeof evilObject1 === 'string' ? evilObject1 : "BAD OBJECT1"
const sanitized2 = typeof evilObject2 === 'string' ? evilObject2 : "BAD OBJECT2"

const strInter = `Seemingly innocent object, interpolated: ${sanitized1}`;
const strConcat = "Seemingly innocent object, concatenated: " + sanitized2;
```

With this fix, you avoid implicitly calling `toString()` on an unsafe object. Either the objects you got were strings, and those will be used, or else they weren't, and you'll get the "BAD OBJECT" text instead.