# ES6 template statement versus eval()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm considering to do an independent parsing for `${something}` variables in a text string, to execute `eval()` on them and replace within the resulting string.

Is there any specific to ES6 template variables to be aware of? Anything that makes them behave different from the way the standard `eval()` does it?

Example:

```
var value = // a string, number, object,... anything;

var a = `${value}`; // use ES6 template string
var b = '${value}'.replace('${value}', eval(value));
```

In which ways and why the results for `a` and `b` can differ?

Comment: There is: The returned result will be part of the string literal.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's not what I asked, there is no need to state the obvious here.

Comment: Have you checked the spec? `eval` isn't a replacement for how template string variables work.

Comment: Nope, should work just fine, as long as you take care of any vulnerabilities this may introduce if the strings you are parsing are from an untrusted source.

Comment: @ssube I didn't think or say that it was... I asked about differences in the way the two approaches work, to consider it when parsing a string.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*template variable*"

Comment: I have no idea of what you want to know then. I've answered to your question. Running ``alert`${1}`;`` and `alert(eval('1'));` has that difference!

Comment: @KevinB thank you! I hope to make a detailed list of such differences. Although by the look of how eager some people to hand down down-votes here, not sure I will find my answer here...

Comment: If you ask about eval, in any way that is different from "don't use eval", you will get downvotes.

Comment: @KevinB seems that way, LOL, a very sad LOL :(

Comment: @vitaly-t: It would help if you'd include actual code in your question. Your description of what you "consider to do" is not enough to give a reasonable answer, I have no idea how you'd want to use `eval` in a way that could be similar to the behaviour of template literals.

Comment: @Bergi done, example added.

Comment: in what ways can the example change?

Comment: @vitaly-t: well that doesn't work like you think it does. It would work better (closer to the template literal) if you'd just omit the `eval` call and replace the substitution pattern with `value`

Comment: @KevinB the `value` can be anything.

Comment: @Bergi, improving the example would be beside the point. An explanation of how different it would work though would be right to the point.

Comment: well.. your example doesn't really make much sense in it's current form, so... improving it would make it something we could build on. In the current example, `value` is a string, and your evaling the string. it's going to throw an exception because `any kind of value` isn't valid javascript.

Comment: Why are you evaling at all here though? The only case where eval would make a difference is if the value was a string that contained valid javascript. If it's a number function or object, eval doesn't benefit you in any way, and it certainly wouldn't make b equal to a in the case of `value` being a string.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34935982/es2015-template-strings-security-issue

Comment: @Bergi yea it is a really good answer, maybe we can get its author to chime in on this issue :P /s

Comment: Sometimes just would love a nuke button here to take out own question and half the website with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
var a = 'test';

var str1 = `${a} ${a} ${a}`; //test test test
var str2 = '${a} ${a} ${a}'.replace('${a}', a); //test ${a} ${a}
```

Also, consider the following:

```
var str1 = `${Math.random()} ${Math.random()}` //0.7818185299239435 0.8991473634359528
var str2 = '${Math.random()} ${Math.random()}'.replace('${Math.random()}', Math.random()); //0.9327690218686401 ${Math.random()}
```

Remember that anything inside `${...}` will be evaluated as code, and it's result will be used in the string.

You can argue about using regular expressions and what-not, But also consider this:

```
var str1 = `${5+`${Math.random()}`}`; //50.11300474012906858
```

Yes, template strings can be nested! How would you handle it with replaces?

---

So, in a small list:

- Everything will be evaluated
- Template strings can be nested
- The result will be part of the string
- The result may change between executions

Those are the differences.

---

You may ask about security. Well, it is no more or less dangerous than `var a = eval('str')` or `var a = Function('return str')()`.

But, there is a twist: It will run `.toString()` on the returned value. The smallest verifyable example is the following:

```
alert(`${{}}`) // calling alert`${{}}` will only show ","
```

If somehow you manage to use your method, with this hypothetical way:

```
alert('${R}'.replace( /\$\{(\w[\w\d]*)\}/g, (_, v) => eval(v)));
```

You are relativelly safe*! <sup>Relativelly to nothing</sup>

However, be **very** careful with `eval` vs. `window.eval`!!!

Here's an example:

```
window.R = {
    toString: _ => 'evil'
};
(window => {
    var R = 'nice';

    //Using evil! erm ... eval()
    alert('${R}'.replace( /\$\{(\w[\w\d]*)\}/g, (_, v) => eval(v)));

    //Using MOAR window.evil! erm ... window.eval()
    alert('${R}'.replace( /\$\{(\w[\w\d]*)\}/g, (_, v) => window.eval(v)));

    //String templates
    alert(`${R}`);

})(window)
```

It should show "nice, evil, nice". This means that `window.eval` runs on global scope, while `eval` runs on local scope. That is the only safety issue that I saw besides the ones that already exist with `eval()`.

Putting it in a short way, your method would be as safe as using a string template.

Comment: Template strings can be nested - is the only good example here. The rest are just technicalities / obvious, I would just skip them ;) Other good points I thought would be about security...?

Comment: @vitaly-t Give me some time, since I'm still at work. But all those points are obvious to you, but may not be obvious to someone else reading.

Comment: Take your time, i'm off for the day.