# Is there XSS risk when using a template literal with an untrusted string to set an attribute value?

Tags: ecmascript-6, xss, template-literals

I'm building an iframe, not with `innerHTML`, but with `createElement`.. I have two untrusted strings that are used:

```
iframeEl.title = untrustedStr1;
iframeEl.src = `http://example.com/?id=${untrustedStr2}`;
```

According to the OWASP XSS cheatsheet, the `title` attribute is [totally safe](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#:%7E:text=Safe%20HTML%20Attributes%20include), so I'm not worried about that.

However, I'm not 100% sure about the `iframeEl.src` case.

I'm thinking about the [5 significant characters](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#:%7E:text=The%205%20characters) that typically need to be encoded: `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, and `'` and I don't see any way to escape out of the template literal. And I also don't see a mechanism to have `untrustedStr2` run as JavaScript. (For example, if `untrustedStr2 = 'document.cookie'`, it's interpolated as a string, not via evaluation).

I suppose if `untrustedStr2` is a getter method somehow, I could have a problem. But if it's absolutely a string, this is safe and I don't need to encode, not even for the 5 significant characters. Is that right?

Comment: [I don't see what this has to do with template literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34935982/1048572). `iframeEl.src = "http://example.com/?id=" + untrustedStr2;` has exactly the same issues (and non-issues).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with the DOM, there are no *html encoding* issues in *any* element properties. The characters `<`, `>`, `&`, `"`, and `'` do not need escaping.

However, you still need to deal with the semantics of the respective attribute. While `title` is just a plain string that's not used for anything but displaying tooltips, others are not safe:

- `on…` event handlers contain javascript code. It's a bad practice to assign strings to them anyway, but if you do, interpolating values must follow javascript escaping rules.
  ⇨ [Rule #3](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-3-be-careful-when-inserting-untrusted-data-into-the-event-handler-and-javascript-code-subcontexts-within-an-execution-context)
- `style` properties contain CSS rules which need their own escaping.
  ⇨ [Rule #4](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-4-javascript-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-the-css-attribute-subcontext-within-the-execution-context)
- `src` or `href` attributes are urls that the browser will load at some point. Those definitely are sensitive, and when interpolating values into urls you need to follow URL encoding rules.
  ⇨ [Rule #5](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-5-url-escape-then-javascript-escape-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-url-attribute-subcontext-within-the-execution-context)
- … *(not meant to be exhaustive)*

In your particular case, if you fail to url-encode the `untrustedStr2`, the attacker may send arbitrary query parameters or fragments to `example.com`. This is not a security issue in itself if example.com isn't susceptible to reflected XSS (the attacker may send the same link to the user via other channels), but it is broken functionality (undesired behaviour), but still it's your page endorsing the linked content.

So if `untrustedStr2` is meant as a value of the `id` URI query parameter, you should definitely use

```
iframeEl.src = `http://example.com/?id=${encodeURIComponent(untrustedStr2)}`;
//                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely for `untrustedStr2` to evaluate and/or break out of the string. However if you don't encode it you may allow "HTTP Parameter Pollution (HPP)".

```js
// untrustedStr2 = '9&id=42';
iframeEl.src = `http://example.com/?id=${untrustedStr2}`;
```

> By itself, this is not necessarily an indication of vulnerability. However, if the developer is not aware of the problem, the presence of duplicated parameters may produce an anomalous behavior in the application that can be potentially exploited by an attacker. As often in security, unexpected behaviors are a usual source of weaknesses that could lead to HTTP Parameter Pollution attacks in this case.

See https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/v41/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/07-Input_Validation_Testing/04-Testing_for_HTTP_Parameter_Pollution.html

Or you could allow an attempt at a CSRF attack:

```js
// untrustedStr2 = '9&action=delete';
iframeEl.src = `http://example.com/?id=${untrustedStr2}`;
```

I think it would be safer to encode it.

Comment: Agreed, but if a **`GET`** request to `http://example.com/?id=9&action=delete` causes a deletion that's a security issue in example.com itself.

Comment: @Bergi I know and you are correct of course. But we can secure the web for ourselves and others too.